# How to Test an SharePoint site Page with Cypress

Tags: sharepoint, automated-tests, cypress, ui-automation, sharepoint-online

Does cypress support SharePoint site E2E testing? How to run E2E testing using cypress for SharePoint Sites

Below I have mentioned the code for generating access tokens using client id secret value. I have stored the token in local storage but after that, it was not opening any SharePoint site it's open the Microsoft sign In page.

**Commands.js**

```
Cypress.Commands.add('generateToken', () => {
  cy.request({
    // Given: I send auth request
    url: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantID}/oauth2/token',
    method: "POST",
    header: {
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    },
    form: true,
    body: {
      grant_type: 'password',
      tenant: '',
      client_id: '',
      client_secret: '',
      resource: '',
      username: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }).its('body')
    .then((body) => {
      // When: I get a token
      cy.log('token......', body.access_token);
      window.localStorage.setItem("access_token", body.access_token);
      window.localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", body.refresh_token);
    });
});
```

Below I have mentioned the tests case which I have created.

```
import '../../support/commands';

describe('example to-do app', () => {
  it('Visits the site as logged in user', () => {
    cy.generateToken();
    cy.wait(3000);
    cy.visit('https://onlinesharepoints.sharepoint.com/sites/abcdev/Pages/test-Angular.aspx');
  })
})
```

**Below mention a screenshot of cypress results:**
[image: Cypress Test Result]

Comment: You may want to add an assertion to your request to ensure the token is generated. Additional, I'd implement [cypress-recurse](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-recurse) until it is successful.